# How to update / refresh glyphs programmatically in Solution Explorer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility, solution-explorer

I've created VSIX package which displays file statuses as glyphs in Solution Explorer in VS2010. I implemented basic SccProvider (inherited from IVsSccProvider, IVsSccManager2, IVsSccGlyphs and others) including GetSccGlyph method. So when solution opens vsix package successfully loads the initial glyphs for the whole solution. But I can't find a way how to update specific (or whole) solution item's glyph. The appropriate way should looks like

```
var rgsiGlyphs = new VsStateIcon[1];
var rgdwSccStatus = new uint[1];
GetSccGlyph(1, new[] { itemFilePath }, rgsiGlyphs, rgdwSccStatus);
hierarchy.SetProperty(itemId, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_StateIconIndex, rgsiGlyphs[0]);
```

where **itemId** - is specific project item id. Unfortunately this approach works only for solution, but doesn't update glyphs for project / class item types. I read there is another way how to force glyphs refresh for all project child items

```
sccProject2.SccGlyphChanged(0, null, null, null);
```

but it doesn't work as well. I also read that glyph statuses can be cached in Scc and this refresh should be forced somehow, but again I didn't find any correct reference.

I know it is possible, because VisualSvn and other similar plugins somehow updates glyphs dynamically. Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a package, you are supposed to implement the [IVsHierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchy.aspx) interface. When you do so, you must implement the [AdviseHiearchyEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchy.advisehierarchyevents.aspx) method. In this method, you must add the passed in sink to a collection you keep, something like this:

```
    int IVsUIHierarchy.AdviseHierarchyEvents(IVsHierarchyEvents eventSink, out uint cookie)
    {
        cookie = _sinkCookie++; // come up with some unique cookie
        _eventSinks.Add(cookie, eventSink); // remember this sink
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }

    int IVsUIHierarchy.UnadviseHierarchyEvents(uint cookie)
    {
        _eventSinks.Remove(cookie);
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }
```

And now, you can raise property changed events when you need, like this:

```
    private void NotifySccChange()
    {
        foreach (sink in _eventSinks)
        {
            try
            {

                sink.OnPropertyChanged(MyId, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_StateIconIndex, 0);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SinkIsDead(sink);
            }
        }
    }
```